# Meteor #each Table grow size bigger than HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, meteor

I have a Meteor project which I just need to list a bunch of orders on a HTML table.  But when the table gets too big, it overlaps my DIV like this:

[image]

At first I thought that this could be a CSS problem, but then I noticed that the HTML tag size is SMALLER than my table size:

[image]

Now I'm a bit lost, I already set all my DIVs to have a 100% height, but because the HTML tag size is static (for some reason :confused: ), the table overlaps my DIVs. Here is how I'm generating my table:

```
{{#if isNewOrder}}
    <h2 style="margin-left: 30px"> Pedidos Pendentes </h2>
    <table cellspacing='0'>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Cliente</th>
            <th>Telefone</th>
            <th>Valor</th>
            <th>Operações</th>
        </tr>
    {{#each tablecontent}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{id}}</td>
            <td>{{prettifyDate timestamp}}</td>
            <td>{{name}}</td>
            <td>{{phone}}</td> 
            <td>{{prettifyPrice price}}</td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Detalhes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Aceitar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Rejeitar</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
    </table>
{{/if}}
```

No big deal right? I have two session variables (`isNewOrder` and `tablecontent`), `isNewOrder` tells if I should show that table or not, and `tablecontent` contains all the elements of my table.

So, am I missing something about big lists with Meteor? Or could it really be a problem with my CSS (despite I set all DIVs to 100% of height).

Best Regards, Ernani

Comment: You need to look at the css overflow property. You might also want to think about paginating your data

Comment: Hello @Mikkel I thought about using overflow:scroll but it duplicates the scroll bar and becames kind of confusing

Comment: Yes double scroll bars is annoying. I'm not an expert in this space, but there is a way to fix it. I suspect it is to make the height of the container 100%

Comment: Yes, I manage to remove one scroll by setting the height to 99%. But now there is a blank space between the end of the window and the scroll.